# Selenium mock server access

Tags: stub, sahi, dummy-data

I have a website that I want to test using Selenium WebDriver (version 2.28), and to integrate it with my CI (Maven and Hudson).

The thing is that in order to properly test the front-end, I need to access the server (for the actual HTML and for REST resources). The test will not be fully encapsulated if I access the actual server that I build and deploy during the build process, since the data might be different each time (based on the data that resides in the DB of the built environment at the time of the build).

Therefore it seems to me that I have to mock the server access.
I just don't find a support for this in Selenium, and I can't quite think of the best way to do that without a Selenium support.

I can create mocks to all of my resources (HTML and REST) in the actual server, on different URLs, and access those in my tests instead of the production-level ones (with some kind of a flag to indicate that I should access mock resources instead of real ones). But that's not really mocking...

For reference, I saw that in the Sahi test framework there's a feature of addMock(url, class_function) - in which when Sahi runs into the specified URL, it will call the specified class and function instead of access the URL, whereas the class and function should provide the resource instead of the URL providing the resource.

I'm looking for something similar in Selenium (though perhaps it's not possible, since Sahi functions as a proxy).

Many thanks in advance,
Daniel

Comment: Even if you can mock the initial page download, will Selenium also allow to mock downloading *page elements*? Like scripts, images, etc... (once the initial page HTML is resolved)